# Can't start app from launcher in Android

Tags: android, launcher, htc-android

My application is able to run from the launcher on the Galaxy Tab, but on the HTC Legend, I get the following error in logcat:

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/Rosie   (  194): can't start activity: android.intent.action.MAIN
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/ActivityManager(   97): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.company.myapp/.Myapp }
W/ActivityManager(   97): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUid=10015
W/ActivityManager(   97): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.company.myapp/.Myapp } from ProcessRecord{450f1ac8 194:com.htc.launcher/9999} (pid=194, uid=9999) requires null
```

My manifest file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.company.myapp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">        
    <activity android:name="com.company.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity><activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name" android:multiprocess="true" android:configChanges="orientation" android:name="Myapp">
    </activity><activity android:name="com.company.CameraActivity" android:multiprocess="true" android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.company.MainMenu">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.company.ImagePicker">
    </activity>        
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</manifest>
```

**Edit: Fix**

Just had to uninstall from device and reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the OP. I edited my question for the fix, but here it is also:

Just had to uninstall from device and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty `<uses-permission></uses-permission>` element in your manifest. Try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the line in your manifest that declares an empty permission.  It's possible the system doesn't know how to handle that (see the null warning).

Delete this line:

```
<uses-permission></uses-permission>
```

Comment: You're declaring the min SDK as 8 (Android 2.2 aka Froyo).  Is your HTC legend on 2.2?  If not then it won't work for it.  You need your app to support level 7 and higher.

Comment: Yup it is 2.2, it runs on first upload, just not from launcher.